# Convert lists to dict python?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like this :

```py
[
    ["key=djbjd","val=22"],
    ["key=fvv","val=34"],
    ...
]
```

How can I convert it into one single `dict` of the following format:

```
{"djbjd":"22",
 "fvv":"34"
 ...
}
```

Comment: 1. iterate over the list 2. parse each entry 3. add each key/value pair to the dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
lsts = [["key=fvv","val=34"],["key=djbjd","val=22"]]
result = {i[0].split("=")[1]: i[1].split("=")[1] for i in lsts}
print(result)
```

output

```
{'fvv': '34', 'djbjd': '22'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `key=` and `val=` are both 4 character prefixes, you can just strip those characters off and feed the transformed list to `dict()`:

```
>>> data = [
...     ["key=djbjd","val=22"],
...     ["key=fvv","val=34"],
... ]
>>> dict((i[4:] for i in t) for t in data)
{'djbjd': '22', 'fvv': '34'}
```